# Closed form of an expression.

Tags: summation

I want to show $\dfrac{1}{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(2\pi mx)}{m}= -(x-[x]-\dfrac{1}{2})$,when x is not an integer,where [x] denotes greatest integer function .
Could you please give any suggestion how to approach??
Thanks

Comment: What do you know about Fourier series?

Comment: Is it related to Poisson Summation formula? I can't see any connection with fourier series.

Comment: @HitendraTendutolian The left hand side is a Fourier series, in that it's an infinite series of terms from the usual Fourier basis. Try computing the Fourier series for $-(x - [x] - 1/2)$, and see if it matches the left. Then, the Fourier series and the function should agree whenever the function is continuous, i.e. when $x$ is not an integer.

Comment: okay,got it. thanks.I am gonna try .If I stuck somewhere I will ask.